# VSCode Java Debugger "Error Unable to open 'thing.java': File not found (\thing.java)."

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am receiving this error when try to debug java in VSCode:
`Error Unable to open 'thing.java': File not found (\thing.java).`

The debugger seems to be running (my code is paused, I can see local variables and step through, but the source code is not being shown).

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
  "name": "Java",
  "type": "java",
  "request": "launch",
  "stopOnEntry": true,
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "startupClass": "my.package.classname",
  "options": [
    "-classpath",
    "${workspaceRoot}/bin"      
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the source code to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears [javaVSCode](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/javaVSCode) (Java debugger for VSCode) is having trouble locating the source files.  This was an [issue](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/javaVSCode/issues/1) for this, and it appears to be fixed.

Unfortunately there was no documentation.  So, after looking through the merge and some experimentation, the answer is to:

**Add the "sourcePaths" option to your configuration**

eg.

```
{
  "name": "Java",
  "type": "java",
  "request": "launch",
  "stopOnEntry": true,
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
  "sourcePaths": ["${workspaceRoot}/src/my/package"],
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "startupClass": "my.package.classname",
  "options": [
    "-classpath",
    "${workspaceRoot}/bin"      
  ]
}
```

Comment: sourcePath has now chagned to sourcePaths

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen if you don't have JAVA_HOME set to your environment:

Run in terminal: 
**echo $JAVA_HOME**

If nothing appears, just set it:
**export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/your-jdk-version/**