# I'm having trouble with java debugging in vscode(Visual Studio Code), especially with 'launch.json'

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble with java programming in vscode.

I already installed two extensions below.
'Java Debug Extension for Visual Studio Code'
'Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat'

When I push 'F5' to debug, this message comes up.

[image]

I click 'yes', then 'launch.json' is created in my folder 'C:/vscode_java'.

And I don't know what to write in 'launch.json'.

What do I have to do to make my code run in vscode?

Comment: That extension has a list of items in its description for the launch and attach portions of your launch.json.  Such as "mainClass (required) - The main class of the program (fully qualified name, e.g. com.xyz.MainClass)."  Try to follow that first and then show your code.

Comment: And this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.javadebugger debugger extension seems to have better documentation.  And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022422/vscode-java-debugger-error-unable-to-open-thing-java-file-not-found-thing for its use.