# When debugging java, "Unable to open 'blah.java': resource is not available"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm running VSCode (v1.26.1) with the Java Extension Pack (v0.3.0) for remote debugging.  When execution hits a breakpoint, VSCode does not open the file, though it correctly displays the filename in the call stack:

[image]

Instead, it displays the error:

[image]

I have the following in my launch.json:

[image]

Adding the `sourcePaths` property got VSCode to display the filename in the call stack for the line of code with the breakpoint.  It previously displayed *Unknown Source*. But it still can't open the file.  It appears that `sourcePaths` has only enabled VSCode to "sort of" find the source file.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get it to open the file when it hits the breakpoint (or when I click on the file in the call stack)?

Note: This question is different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022422/vscode-java-debugger-error-unable-to-open-thing-java-file-not-found-thing) in that I'm using Java Extension Pack's *Debugger for Java* and not the deprecated *javaVSCode* that was being used by the asker of that question.